# sed wildcard substitution

Tags: regex, sed, grep, wildcard, string-substitution

I want to do a substitution based on a wildcard. For example, change all "tenure" to "disposition" only if the word "tenure" comes after an '=' sign. Basically a regex that would match this `=.*tenure`

The sed command that I have so for this is:

```
sed 's/=.*tenure/=.*disposition/g' file.txt
```

However, if I pass this to a file containing:

```
blah blah blah = change "tenure" to "disposition"
```

I get

```
blah blah blah =.*disposition" to "disposition"
```

instead of:

```
blah blah blah = change "disposition" to "disposition"
```

How do I do the substitution such that the wildcard in the regex won't be part of the destination file?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to use a **capturing group** to capture the text that appears between your equals sign and "tenure".

So

```bsh
sed 's/=\(.*\)tenure/=\1disposition/g'
```

Note the use of `\1` to reference and use the group you captured.

So in

```bsh
echo 'blah blah blah = change "tenure" to "disposition"' | sed 's/=\(.*\)tenure/=\1disposition/g'
```

we get

```
blah blah blah = change "disposition" to "disposition".
```

See [Regex grouping](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html).

Answer (score 2):

```
sed 's/\(=.*\)tenure/\1disposition/g' file.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to save matched characters between the `=` and the `tenure` to add them to the output:

```
sed 's/=(.*)tenure/=\1disposition/g' file.txt
```

Also, you should add the `-i` option to sed if you want to edit the file inplace (do the modifications to the file itself).

Answer (score 2):

You have to use [backreference](http://toytoygogie.blogspot.com/2010/02/using-sed-with-backreference-as.html) in sed. Use it like this:

```
sed 's/\(=.*\)tenure/\1disposition/g'
```